# Maximum in Functions

Tags: functions

I have this math question here:

**Suppose the function $$ d(t) = t^2-14t $$ is the depth of a scuba diver at t time, as she dives underwater, reaches a certain depth, and swims back to the surface. 
What is the maximum depth, if at 4 seconds she reaches a depth of 40m?**

I got a maximum depth of 48 by plugging in numbers into a graph - can anyone explain this in more detail and why this works? :-)

Comment: This cannot be the maximum depth since $\lim_{t \to \infty} d(t) = \infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat As the question makes clear, we are interested in the minimum value of $d(t)$

Comment: @almagest: The question asks for the maximum depth, which is unbounded above. Minus signs make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

$-d(t) = -t^2+14t = -(t-7)^2 + 49\leq 49$. Thus the max depth would be $49$ meters.

Answer (score 0):

If we differentiate distance w.r.t. time then we get velocity. And at the maximum depth, her velocity should be $0$. So, by differentiating the function and putting it equal to $0$, we get the time when the velocity was $0$. And at that time the displacement (depth) is maximum.

In other words, at the maximum depth the change in distance is $0$. And by differentiating we get the degree by which the function is changing. It means $2t-14=0$. So $t=7$. When we put $t=7$ in our original equation we get the depth.